# Firebase app distribution using fastlane through github action?

Tags: android, firebase, github, github-actions, fastlane

I am new to `Fastlane` and distributing the app using the `Firebase` app distribution on a `Github` action.

## FastLane file

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
 desc "Runs all the tests"
 lane :test do
  gradle(task: "test")
end

desc "Build and submit to Firebase App distribution Internal users"
lane :dev do

firebase_app_distribution(
  app: "some -app -ID",
  groups: "internal-testers",
  release_notes_file: "FirebaseAppDistributionConfig/dev_notes.txt",
)
end
end
```

## Github Actions

```
name: Distribute

on:
 push:
   branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  distribute:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
    with:
      ruby-version: '2.6'
  
  - name: Install bundle
    run: |
      bundle config path vendor/bundle
      bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3     

  - name: Create Firebase Service Credentials file
    run: |
      echo "$FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS" > firebase_credentials.json.b64
      base64 -d -i firebase_credentials.json.b64 > firebase_credentials.json
    env:
      FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS }}
      
  - name: Distribute app with  App Distribution 
    run: bundle exec fastlane dev
    env:
      FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
```

Whenever I am committing to the master branch, I am getting "`Couldn't find binary`". Here is an attached screenshot of GitHub action terminal

[image]

I even added all `secrets` to GitHub repository. However, If I run `bundle exec fastlane dev`. It's working fine and I can see the new APK uploaded to the firebase app distribution platform.

Any hint what am I doing wrong here? Is there a way that I can see the stack trace why
fastlane is not able to find the apk?

Comment: have you found the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are missing this plugin
**bundle exec fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution**

**This is Compele workflow:**

```yaml
name: Flutter
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.7'

      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: '17'
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: 'stable'

      - name: Clean Flutter Dependencies.
        run: flutter clean

      - name: Get Flutter Dependencies.
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Cache Ruby - Bundler
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: vendor/bundle
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gems-${{ hashFiles('**/Gemfile.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gems-

      - name: Cache Gradle
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches/
          key: cache-clean-gradle-${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.jdk }}

      - name: Cache Gradle Wrapper
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/wrapper/
          key: cache-clean-wrapper-${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.jdk }}

      - name: Install bundle
        run: |
          cd android   # Change directory to the android directory where Gemfile is located
          bundle config path vendor/bundle   # Configure Bundler to use vendor/bundle directory
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3 # Install gems specified in Gemfile
          
      - name: Set environment variables from secrets
        run: |
          echo "FIREBASE_APP_ID=${{ secrets.APP_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "FIREBASE_TOKEN=${{ secrets.TOKEN }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Build Gradle
        run: flutter build apk --debug

      - name: Add Firebase App Distribution Plugin
        run: |
          cd android
          bundle exec fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution

      - name: Distribute app with  App Distribution 
        run: |
          cd android   
          bundle exec fastlane distribute
```

**and this Fastfile**

```
default_platform(:android)
platform :android do

    desc "Lane for distributing app using Firebase App Distributions"
    lane :distribute do
        firebase_app_distribution(
            firebase_cli_token: ENV["FIREBASE_TOKEN"],
            app: ENV['FIREBASE_APP_ID'],
            release_notes: "last build",
            groups: "tester",
            debug: true,
            android_artifact_type: "APK",
            firebase_cli_path: "/usr/local/bin/firebase",
            apk_path: '../build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk'
        )
    end
end
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem; it works for me.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the apk or bundle file absolute path by using

```
desc "Build and submit to Firebase App distribution Internal users"
lane :dev do |options|

firebase_app_distribution(
  app: "some -app -ID",
  groups: "internal-testers",
  release_notes_file: "FirebaseAppDistributionConfig/dev_notes.txt",
  android_artifact_path: "type it here directly or 
                          pass it through terminal>>" options[:buildPath]
)
end
```

If you want to use pass it from the terminal :

```
bundle exec fastlane dev buildPath:"must be the full path to the artifact!! something like this>../app/build/outputs/apk/dev/release/app-dev-release.apk"
```